# Cyanogenmod for Galaxy Y

Tags: cyanogenmod, 2.3-gingerbread, rom-flashing, custom-roms

I have a Samsung galaxy Y device. It's running Gingerbread stock rom, and I want to upgrade this to Jellybean. Is there any custom rom for Galaxy Y?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yup, there are plenty of ROMS out there for Samsung Galaxy Y, as per your requirement, the most recent cyangogen mod is CM11 (kitkat, better than jellybean) for it. The complete installation instructions and step by step tutorial can be found [here](http://www.galaxyyarchive.info/2014/06/cyanogenmod11-for-samsung-galaxy-y-gt.html).

Comment: Whilst this may theoretically answer the question, [it would be preferable](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/8259) to include the essential parts of the answer here, and provide the link for reference. EDIT: The question is a duplicate anyway, no point in this case!

Comment: is it bug free....?

Comment: i haven't tried it but most custom ROMS have some bugs in them